# Laravel queries in route / controller / model etc

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Another one of those questions...

Trying to get to the bottom of how to properly do this.

So currently I have a route like so:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('pages/home');
});
```

And in that page I have:

```
$builds = DB::table('blogs')->where('frontpage', '1')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);

foreach ($builds as $build) {
  // do stuff
}
```

This works, but I know that queries should not be done in the view itself. Where should they be and how can I get the data into the view best?

So far, the only other way I can get it working is by putting the query in the route itself and compacting the variable:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
  $builds = DB::table('blogs')->where('frontpage', '1')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
  return View::make('pages/home', compact('builds'));
});
```

But I believe that is also not correct?

I have also tried putting a function into my model:

```
public static function findBuilds(){
    DB::table('blogs')->where('frontpage', '1')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
}
```

And then in the route:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
  $builds = Blog::findBuilds();
  return View::make('pages/home', compact('builds'));
});
```

But that gives me an error of non object when I try to use my ->links function for pagination in the view.

What should I be doing? Once I know once ill be fine :)

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to do so much logic in routes in the first place? For your class not found issue, it depends on your autoloader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `return` statement in your `findBuilds` method:

```
public static function findBuilds()
{
    return DB::table('blogs')->where('frontpage', '1')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
//  ^^^^^^ 
}
```

That said, since you're anyhow in the model, use the model instead of falling back to the `DB` class:

```
public static function findBuilds()
{
    return static::where('frontpage', '1')->latest('id')->paginate(20);
}
```

Comment: Ahh how could i forget the return -.- thanks worked a charm. Also thanks for the rework on the query, need to look at some of these options like latest.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally you might put this logic into your `Controller`, rather than in your routes.php, Model or View - for your case it might be a Controller called: `PagesController`:

**/app/routes.php**

```
// tell Laravel to route all requests to /pages/ to your PagesController
Route::controller('pages', 'PagesController');
```

**/app/controllers/PagesController.php**

```
// now create your routes in PagesController:
class PagesController extends BaseController {

    // handles: GET pages/home
    public function getHome()
    {
        $builds = DB::table('blogs')
                    ->where('frontpage', '1')
                    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                    ->paginate(20);
        // pass your $builds to your view
        return View::make('pages/home')->with('builds', $builds);
    }
}
```

**/app/views/pages/home.blade.php**  Use the [blade syntax](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates) to extract the various attributes and values for each element in your `$builds` array

```
@foreach($builds as $build)
// do something with the elements of your builds array
   <div class="build">
     <h2>{{ $build->name }}</h2>
     <!-- etc etc etc-->
   </div>
@endforeach
```

If you are building a small application this might be overkill.. so you do want to do this in your `routes.php`, just add this logic into the route and use the same [blade syntax](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates) to loop through your `$builds`:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $builds = DB::table('blogs')->where('frontpage', '1')
                                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                                ->paginate(20);
    return View::make('pages/home')->with('builds', $builds);
});
```

(note - this is not good practice for bigger applications, with lots of routes.  Your routes.php will fill up and make your life harder.. use Controllers if you can!)

Comment: Never thought of having a page controller, ill look at implementing that :)

Comment: @user2921557 well... maybe you don't need it for a small app.. but I generally find it easier to organise myself with Controllers, rather than having a huge routes.php! :) good luck!